# Summable complex sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $V = \{ v \in \ell^2 \setminus \lvert \sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n \rvert < \infty \}$ be the subspace of $\ell^2$ over $\Bbb C$ of summable complex sequences

Let $U=\overline{V}$ and be $u \in U-V$

I would like to know if $u$ is summable $\lvert \sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \rvert < \infty$

Comment: I changed \space \backslash \space to \setminus. That is standard usage.

Comment: ok thanks @MichaelHardy

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. $u$ is not a generic element of $\ell^2$

Comment: Doesn't "summable" mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n | < \infty$ rather than $\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \right|<\infty\text{?}\qquad$

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. i don't understand because in your example $u,v \in V$

Comment: @MichaelHardy summable i mean just i wrote

Comment: Unless I missed something, $U=\bar{U}=V$ (these are vector subspaces). Then $U-V=U$ and this is trivial, no ? even with the stronger requirement $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n | < \infty$.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. not as you say but $U=\overline{V}$

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. : Vector subspaces in infinite-dimensional spaces are not always closed.

Comment: @MateyMath For any vector subspace $U-U=U$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It seems one does not need closure.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. $U-U=\emptyset$

Comment: @MateyMath In this context "minus" is the [Minkowski operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) ($-$ is different from $\setminus$)

Comment: It seems that $U-V$ was intended to mean what is sometimes denoted by $U\setminus V$, i.e. it contains everything in $U$ that's not in $V$, whereas Duchamp Gérard H. E. may be construing it as $\{x-y : x\in U\ \&\ y\in V\}. \qquad$

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. i meant the compement of $U$

Comment: yes @MichaelHardy it is so

Comment: @MateyMath : $U\setminus V$ is the complement of $V$ relative to $U$, not the "complement of $U$". $\qquad$

Comment: By closure, do you mean the $\ell^2$ closure?

Comment: sorry you are right @MichaelHardy

Comment: the completion i meant

Comment: Perhaps the OP search for an example such that $v_m(n)=1/n$ for $1\leq n\leq m$, $v_m(n)=0$ for $n\geq m+1$, and $v(n)=1/n$ for $n\geq 1$; then $v_m\in V$ for all $m$, $v_m\to v$ (in $l^2$) but $v\not \in V$ ?

Comment: thanks @Kelenner but i think my question is the contrary i should konw if $v \in U$ not if $v \in V$

Comment: If $u \in U \setminus V$ it **cannot** be summable by definition, since $V$ contains all the summable sequences.

Comment: ok @copper.hat you're right, so my question becames is $V$ closed?

Comment: @Matey Math But, $U\setminus V=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

since the zero sequence is in V, if every $u\in U-V$ is summable (in your sense) then $\bar{V}=V$. And reciprocally.

Comment: thanks @basti so  $V$ is closed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, in this context "minus" is the [Minkowski operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) ($-$ is different from $\setminus$). Then, unless I missed something, $U=\bar{U}=V$ (these are vector subspaces), one has $U−V=U$ (otherwise $U\setminus V=\emptyset$ and this should be meaningless). All this holds with the stronger requirement $\sum_{n\geq 1}|u_n|<+\infty$ (and $U=\ell^2\cap \ell^1=\ell^1$ in this case).